# Mule ESB: How to handle clob type database value in mule?

Tags: database, mule, esb, clob, connector

I am fetching a `Clob` type value from database in mule flow. 
Please let me know how to handle this type of values in a Data Mapper/ Transform message components of mule?

Comment: please, can you show some code or a snippet of your data?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Questions seeking for help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

[Click here for Mule Flow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzxml.png)

Hi Jimbou,

I have attached screenshot of my mule flow along with the transformer Message flow, which shows my database column type is clob format.

Let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks
Mitali

Comment: please attach image to this question instead of an outside source.